# Execute Midori Command While Running (Raspbian)

Tags: terminal, command, execute, midori

If i type `midori --help-execute` i see many commands  and they seem to be usefull when midori is running, like "Reload", "Forward", etc.

how can i execute these commands, when midori is running?

when i start midori with `midori -a www.google.de` i dont see my typical `username@computer:~$` in the terminal anymore and it does not respond to an execute command like `midori -e Fullscreen` :/ I already tried typing it in a new terminal window

Answer (score 0):

solved: open midori with `midori www.google.de &` then type whatever you want. e.g. `midori -e Fullscreen`